# how to take initial of prefix of docker service name using shell script (which would be stack name in docker swarm)

Tags: shell, docker, docker-swarm

i wanna take initial prefix of docker service name ("UAT_postgres1.gbc38equ81vj6skoknsu83ypz" from this i want UAT as it is also stack name here) and store it in a variable while running shell script to use it later point of time, during script execution.
anyone can please help me.
thanks

Comment: this command  sudo docker service ls  | awk '{ print $2 }'  got me following result NAME
mon_alertmanager
mon_caddy
mon_cadvisor
mon_dockerd-exporter
mon_elasticsearch
mon_grafana
mon_kibana
mon_logstash
mon_node-exporter
mon_prometheus
mon_unsee
from this list i just wanna extract this mon (as it is stack name here) and store it in a variable to use it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know it is the name of the stack, why not just use this instead of piping to awk:

```
NAME=$(docker stack ls --format {{.Name}})
```

If you have just container ID no problem:

```
NAME=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .Config.Labels "com.docker.stack.namespace" }}' <container ID>)
```

Nearly the same if you want to use service ID instead:

```
NAME=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .Spec.Labels "com.docker.stack.namespace" }}' <service ID>)
```

Virtually all docker commands can be formatted in this way to get what you want. This is simple example but it is very useful in other contexts.

Comment: thanks lucidMonkey i got what i wanted with command "NAME=$(sudo docker stack ls --format {{.Name}})"  in this case mon, which was needed to pass as a parameter to another script for updating our services with latest images, automatically. But How to get this particular stackname when more than one stacks are running like one as mon and second one say test.

Comment: Yes its possible to get stackname if we do                                
 CONTAINERID=$(sudo docker ps -q -f name=kibana)                                                   STACKNAME=$(sudo docker inspect --format='{{index .Config.Labels "com.docker.stack.namespace" }}' $CONTAINERID)                                                             echo $STACKNAME                                                                                                       mon